# yq - adding single quotes to a mapping key and adding a key in sorted order

Tags: yq

I've got a Puppet yaml mapping file of the form:

`--- clientinfo::mappings: 'a': key: 12345 'c': key: 23456`

and I want to add

`'b': key: 34567`

I'm unsure how to get it to add the new key/value in sorted order and also how to include the single quotes around the key value.

I tried

`yq -i '.["clientinfo::mappings"].b.key = 34567' ~/clientinfo.yaml`

but it adds the entry after 'c' - and without the quotes. How do I add the quotes and get it in the right order?

`yq -i '.["clientinfo::mappings"] = (.["clientinfo::mappings"] + "ot4" | sort)' ~/clientinfo.yaml`

gets the error

Error: !!str () cannot be added to a !!map (clientinfo::mappings)

With a bit more experimentation I found that

`yq -i ".[\"clientinfo::mappings\"].'b'.key = 34567" ~/clientinfo.yaml`

adds 3 single quotes either side of b.

Just figured out that I can add in whatever order and then run

`yq -i 'sort_keys(..)' ~/clientinfo.yaml`

to fix. But it would be neater to add directly in the right order.

With regard the single quotes, I'm pretty sure that bash's handling of command line arguments is partially or fully to blame. But am unsure of how to get around this.